# how to assign domain to multiple web sites

Tags: iis-7.5

Using IIS 7.5 on 2008 R2, the "mydomain.com" is bind to the default web site and it works as expected, however, I also need to create another web site and bind it to "mydomain.com/othersite", but seems like the bind cannot be done this way. I know that I can assign "mydomain.com/othersite" to an application inside the web site or that I can create another website and bind it to "othesite.com" but this will require another ip address. I need to create several web sites like "mydomain.com/othersite_A", "mydomain.com/othersite_B" and "mydomain.com/othersite_C" 
Is there anyway that I can do it? I think this can be done using "othersite.mydomain.com" but I've no idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DNS set up CNAME or A record for subdomains, like othersite.mydomain.com, all pointing to the same IP address as your main site. Then add that as the binding in IIS